# Angular updating an html element in a table using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to get a table to update using angular where the content of the table will contain some html content like :

```
<ul>
   <li><span style=" font-weight: bold;">Text</span>: 
   <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('comment0');">comment</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I am unable to get the td to compile the html and have tried using ngBindHtml and $compile. Any suggestions?

```
<table>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="row in rows"  >
    <td>{{row.item1}}</td>
    <td>{{row.htmlContent}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `htmlContent` does gave html with angular code like `ng-click`/`ng-focus`?

Comment: I have updated to show an example of the html

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem displaying HTML take a look at 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce